# How do I convert a Column DataType to String in Spark Scala?

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I am trying to call the from_json method and want to fetch the schema of the JSON dynamically. The issue is with the third .withColumn line as it doesn't seem to like Seq[Column].

```
val randomStringGen = udf((length: Int) => {
scala.util.Random.alphanumeric.take(length).mkString
})

val randomKeyGen = udf((key: String, value: String) => {
s"""{"${key}": "${value}"}"""
})

val resultDF = initDF
.withColumn("value", randomStringGen(lit(10)))
.withColumn("keyValue", randomKeyGen(lit("key"), col("value")))
.withColumn("key", from_json(col("keyValue"), spark.read.json(Seq(col("keyValue")).toDS).schema))
```

> error: value toDS is not a member of Seq[org.apache.spark.sql.Column]
> .withColumn("key", from_json(col("keyValue"), spark.read.json(Seq(col("keyValue")).toDS).schema))

I have a known solution which is simply to hard code a sample JSON:

```
val jsData = """{"key": "value"}"""
```

and replace the col("keyValue") with the hardcoded variable.

```
.withColumn("key", from_json(col("keyValue"), spark.read.json(Seq(jsData).toDS).schema))
```

This works and produces exactly what I want, but if I have a large json, then this method can be quite cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 little errors in what you're writing.

First, if you want to use the `toDS` method on a `Seq` you'll need to `import spark.implicits._`. This method is defined in there. Doing that should get rid of your first error.

Secondly, the [`from_json`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#from_json(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,schema:org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) function you're trying to use has the following function signature:

```
def from_json(e: Column, schema: StructType): Column
```

So that second field, `schema`, should be a StructType. This is what the `.schema` method of a Dataset returns. So, one of your parentheses is at the wrong position.

Instead of

```
.withColumn("key", from_json(col("keyValue"), spark.read.json(Seq(col("keyValue")).toDS.schema)))
```

you should have

```
.withColumn("key", from_json(col("keyValue"), spark.read.json(Seq(col("keyValue")).toDS).schema))
```